# How to replace broken trim on side of garage door

Tags: trim, garage-door

My wife clipped the side of the garage door with her mirror as she was backing out of the garage this morning.

[image: Broken door trim - wide angle]

[image: Broken door trim - closeup]

I'm not handy enough to fix it myself, so I'm going to call someone.

First, what sort of repair shop do I call?  The broken piece isn't actually part of the garage door or its mechanisms, so would I necessarily have to call a place that works on garage doors?

Second, is there a better name for the broken part than just "garage door trim"?

Comment: Yeah, blame the wife!  There are lots of YouTube videos on how to replace the trim.    You'll probably have to replace ALL the trim if you want it to match.   If you're lucky, you can find a the exact type/color and just replace the one section.

Comment: Honestly, you could replace this yourself with a hand saw and a screwdriver. The stuff if made out of plastic (cuts very easily) and is either screwed or nailed into place. If yours is nailed, pry it off (add a pry bar to the tool collection), then screw the new stuff back on. Harbor Freight (or equivalent el-cheapo tool store) tools are more than sufficient for this project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That part is Garage door opening side trim. All garage door repair companies would have it. However it is also available at the big box stores and online. A handyman should be able to replace that quickly and cheaper than a Garage door Company.